# External Hard Disk is not accessible. "The disk structure is corrupted and unreadable"

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, chkdsk, bad-sectors

I have a 1 TB AgentGoFlex Seagate external HDD.

Lately it was causing some issues like a few folders which had data were not showing any files.  A few folders were not opening, etc.

So I tried running `chkdsk` on Windows 8, but it did not complete successfully. So I unattached the HDD. Now when I am attaching the HDD to the system, it is not being recognized. In Linux it is not being recognized at all.

While in Win8 when I try to access the disk from command prompt it says "The disk structure is corrupted and unreadable".

Even `chkdsk` is failing now with the error: "The file system is NTFS. Unable to determine volume version and state. chkdsk aborted."

When trying to run the "check utility" from **F:** → right click → Properties → Tools → Check, it gives the below error.

[image: Error screenshot: The disk check could not be performed because Windows can't access the disk]

Formatting the disk is not an option as I have very important data on it.

Please suggest what can be done to enable the access to hard disk.

Comment: If you can't send your disk in to a professional data recovery company the next best solution would be to try to make a image of your disks in it's current state (before the disk fails totally). Then you can keep the image file as a "safe copy", try to recover the disk or a duplicated image file. I am sure Linux at least on some level recognize your drive so try to get some free disk imaging tools and write the image to another disk first!

Comment: I'm afraid Ramhound may be right, your drive may be dead. Data may be recoverable, but doing it at home can result in losing even more files - some professionals may be able to help you. And remember, there are only two kinds of people: those who make backups, and those who will.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, **do not do anything more on the disk** (at least never *write* to it). The disk *not being recognized* (as opposed to "being recognized and found empty or with unreadable data") seems to indicate either a completely blasted disk, which `chkdsk` isn't wont to do, or something wrong with the partition table or geometry of the disk, or the way the USB enclosure handles it. A hardware failure is also possible.

**This can and will happen** when USB enclosures try to negotiate between the disk and the computer they're connected to. So the first thing to do would be to take an image of the disk on a (obviously larger) disk at the closest-to-physical level possible, using `dd` under Linux. Then you can fiddle with an image copy to your heart's content, without risk of further damage to the real disk.

## Update: device recognition in Linux

We have no fewer than *three* entities in our "external disk". The USB enclosure hardware, exposing as a block device. The physical disk inside the enclosure. The physical device, i.e., the sequence of LBA sectors from first to last. And finally zero or more data partitions, hosting the file systems. To be "recognized" and displayed in a desktop, all links of the chains need to be working. But to take an image of the physical device you need only the first two.
If you plug in the device and run the command-line `dmesg` (as root), you ought to see something like this:

```
[4984939.028491] usb 8-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[4984939.166658] usb 8-6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[4984939.170660] scsi7 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[4984939.172003] usb-storage: device found at 3
[4984939.172005] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
```

...which is the enclosure getting recognized, and then identifying itself and its contents:

```
[4984939.170660] usb 8-6: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1021
[4984939.170660] usb 8-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[4984939.170660] usb 8-6: Product: Ext HDD 1021
[4984939.170660] usb 8-6: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[4984939.170660] usb 8-6: SerialNumber: 574D43305431303831303734
[4984944.400970] usb-storage: device scan complete
```

Next you'll see the driver informing of its geometry, nature, and implicitly its device node, here `sdd` (for SCSI Disk Four, since `sda`, `sdb` and `sdc` were already taken):

```
[4984944.404739] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD      Ext HDD 1021    2021 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[4984944.404739] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 1953519616 512-byte hardware sectors (1000202 MB)
[4984944.407367] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[4984944.407369] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 17 00 10 08
[4984944.407371] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[4984944.408741] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 1953519616 512-byte hardware sectors (1000202 MB)
```

Then the kernel recognizes that there is a partition (if you don't see this, the partition is not there or is invalid):

```
[4984944.411497]  sdd: sdd1
```

Now Linux has everything it needs and reports successful attachment:

```
[4984944.416739] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[4984944.416739] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
```

And so the search for data partition begins, i.e., OK, we have `sdd1`, but *what is on there?*, and the answer is:

```
[4984997.498613] NTFS driver 2.1.29 [Flags: R/W MODULE].
[4984997.554613] NTFS volume version 3.1.
[4984997.568859] NTFS-fs error (device sdd1): load_system_files(): $LogFile is not clean.  Mounting read-only.  Mount in Windows.
[4985390.027808] NTFS-fs error (device sdd1): ntfs_remount(): Volume has errors and is read-only.  Cannot remount read-write.
[4985442.423299] NTFS volume version 3.1.
[4985442.425032] NTFS-fs error (device sdd1): load_system_files(): $LogFile is not clean.  Mounting read-only.  Mount in Windows.
```

This above was a "good" mount. But just knowing that the device is `sdd`, or `sdc` or `sdb`, allows me to make a binary copy (assuming I have enough free space on `/mnt/backupdisk`): input file `/dev/sdd`, output file `DiskImage.raw`, [block size 1 MB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9432/is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-optimal-value-for-the-bs-parameter-to-dd):

```
# dd if=/dev/sdd of=/mnt/backupdisk/DiskImage.raw bs=1M
```

**Note** that the input file is `/dev/sdd` *and not* `/dev/sdd1`
(or any other number). 
Now if I wanted to, I could find out the offset of the data partition within `DiskImage.raw`, and mount it with the help of a loop device. [Here](http://wiki.edseek.com/guide:mount_loopback) you'll find the dirty details.

## First recovery attempt

The second thing to do would be to put the physical disk into another enclosure, thereby ensuring the enclosure is good, and getting a chance of the new enclosure correctly interpreting the disk. If the disk reappears, it might have been the previous enclosure that's broken. Just in case, backup all of the newfound drive contents, *verify* the backup, zero the disk with a disk-overwrite utility so that it goes *completely* dumb (you can't have two devices with different opinions in a device chain), reformat it natively from Windows and restore the data. It's a lucky shot, but I saw it happen; and the attempt isn't too expensive, good enclosures going for about US$ 19,99 new.

In case the original enclosure was bad, you won't be able to reformat the disk, or the disk won't be accessible. You can retry the new enclosure, and if it works, either replace the old enclosure, or keep using the new (but this is worthwhile if the new enclosure is *quite* better than a US$ 19.99 El Cheapo).

## Professional recovery

Professional recovery services, those you can find with Google. A not too honest way of going about it would be to send over the physical disk, and – in case you got a "Yes, there is no hardware damage and we can recover all of your data for just US$ $$$,$$$!" answer – well you'd then *know* that the data was still salvageable. So you could attempt doing it yourself for free on the image backup you took, and only pay for the diagnosis and disk S&H. If you failed, the option of coughing up the requested dough would still be there. If there *is* hardware damage, the professional service is basically your **only** option. There are several voodoo tricks that will (temporarily) revive a "dead" disk, often long enough to recover the most important data at least, but **none** that is guaranteed to work each time (heating the disk, cooling it, "twirling" it – I even saw suggested to smartly rap it against a hard surface). All of them will do more damage, i.e., you have to be sure to use the one trick that will work the first time, or you'll have killed the disk forever. I just added this to explain why you'll see success stories about revived disks: there *are* such stories. But if you want to be (mostly) sure it will happen to *you*, well – hire a professional.

If you're sure the hardware is OK – disk spins, no rattles, no strange sounds or buzzes, no clickety-clackety recalibrations – then "all" that happened is that `chkdsk` messed up some data.

## DIY recovery

"Home" recovery usually would go like this (basically the same thing the pro guys would do once hardware damage had been discounted), working on the disk image copy:

- check whether the first sector of the disk image is a valid partition table. If not, scan the disk image looking for either a valid partition table or a recognizable NTFS or FAT32 boot sector, depending on what FS was on the unit (for a 1 TB unit, NTFS seems the only logical possibility). Either way you ought to find something within the first few megabytes.
- if the partition table is found, verify that the data partition is where the partition table says it should be. If it is not, this is very good news: *probably* the partition table is all that's wrong. Fixing it is easy (several Linux partition editors will do that), and the disk may be expected to have a 100% recovery. Just to be on the safe side, try mounting the data partition in Linux with a loop device in read-only mode to see whether it's readable. If it is, partition borking is confirmed, and the disk may be pronounced on its way to sure and full recovery. If it is not, possibly the partition is right and a (part of) a data partition has been rewritten. This is bad; see below under 'things go sour'.
- if it is found and valid, check it against drive geometry and, if they don't match, that's also actually a **good** thing, since you might have found the root cause of the problem. You can force the physical geometry to kernel (and [get it at Linux boot](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/Large-Disk-9.html)). See if the new geometry leads to the disk being recognized in Linux. If it does, backup the data, verify the backup is correct, and zero the disk with `dd` (a couple megabytes of zeroes to the appropriate `sd` device are enough). Power down the computer (don't just reboot; OK, it's paranoid, but it costs little and may accomplish something), then boot up Windows and have it format the now clueless disk into what it thinks is the best format. This ensures no conflicts with Windows. Restore data on the disk. Enjoy.
- if the geometry trick does not work, or the partition can't be found, or once found it appears to be empty, things go sour. You need some recovery tool capable of *scanning* the disk image in search of the data areas (MFT, etc.) of the lost data. And once found, interpret them in order to get at the data. This is a difficult job and can't always be fully automated. At a lower and more desperate level, this involves scanning for the signatures of the *individual* files, hoping that they will lie in contiguous blocks in the disk. This kind of operation I'd gladly leave to professionals, though. I did it several times, always successfully, with old FAT disks. I did it again, about 50% successfully, with newer and larger and more fragmented FAT32 disks. I *attempted* a couple of times, with poor results (but I had full backups and wasn't really giving it my all), on the much more complicated NTFS and ext4 filesystems.

## Manual recovery from Linux

OK, so you try to mount the partition in Linux and get errors (*notice that* `/dev/sdc` *and* `/dev/sdcN` *are different things – the image refers to `/dev/sdc`*).

```
# mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc1 /mnt/recovery
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Record 1 has no FILE magic (0x0)
Failed to open inode $MFTMirr: Input/output error
```

...this seems to indicate that the partition, *as the system believes it to be*, is wrong or badly damaged. Let's check out the first option first:

```
# fdisk /dev/sdc
```

You get something like this:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204885504 bytes
1 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31008335 cylinders, total 1953525167 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x9d2b7596

Device       Boot      Start    End          Blocks       Id  System
/dev/sdc1              63       1953520127   976760032+   7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Next step will be to check the actual partition start. By seeking into the image file (or `/dev/sdc`) we will search for the NTFS signature:

```
  00000000:EB 52 90 4E 54 46 53 20 -20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00 .R.NTFS ........ 
  00000010:00 00 00 00 00 F8 00 00 -3F 00 FF 00 3F 00 00 00 ........?...?... 
  00000020:00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00 -4A F5 7F 00 00 00 00 00 ........J....... 

# dd if=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1 skip=63 2>/dev/null | hexdump -C | head -n 1
```

...with the data above we expect NTFS boot to be at sector 63, that's why we set `skip`. Also, we'll try with *every* sector in the first (say) megabyte...

```
# dd if=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=2000000 2>/dev/null | hexdump -C | grep "00:EB 52 90 4E 54 46 53"
```

...just to be sure there is *only one* boot sector (I had this happen to me. On a FAT32 disk, but *still*) and that there are no read errors anywhere.

Your result

```
00007e00  eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53 20  20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  |.R.NTFS    .....|
```

is exactly what we would expect: sector 63 gives an offset of 63×512 = 32256 = 7e00 hexadecimal. **The NTFS boot sector is there and the partition table appears to be correct**.

So we can now copy a large chunk of `/dev/sdc1` onto, say, `/tmp/mydisk.img` and attempt to fix it from Linux. This won't damage the physical disk, which will still be available unchanged for other attempts. And since now we know the PT to be correct, we can use `/dev/sdc1` for the copy and entertain hopes that we couldn't before:

```
# dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/tmp/mydisk.img bs=1G count=10
...after copying 10 gigabytes...

# ntfsfix /tmp/mydisk.img
```

If NTFSfix does not work, well, we're in trouble. There are [more accurate utilities](http://www.stellarinfo.com) that can be tried, though. And if you need to recover JPEG picture files and the file system wasn't fragmented, this can be done automatically by seeking the JPEG headers. Same, almost, goes for PDF, TIFF and Office documents, except that *I* don't know how to recognize them (for JPEGs, I would :-) ). As a final option I've found [these guys](http://www.lowcostrecovery.com/pricing.html) – I don't know them, am not related to them and won't accept any blame. However, as these things go, the price is *very* reasonable.

Comment: @ Iserni - Thanks for the info. Although very first problem with me is that I can't make the image of HDD on linux because its not being recognized at all. In windows its being detected atleast but is not accessible.

Comment: updating answer re: "unrecognized"

Comment: @Isreni - Thank you very much for the help. I am able make image of data in disk, however data in my disk is 400GB and max available size in my laptop is 200GB. hence I will not be able to make a complete image. It will abort in middle. Is there any way i can only copy 200GB out of 400GB to my laptop and then from that 200gb image recover some data?

Comment: Yes, you can use `dd` with `count` parameter to get only a given number of gigabytes (consider that dd and disk vendors don't agree on how large a GB is -- "200 GB" to one might mean "190 GB" to the other. But also consider that a new *500* GB USB disk costs around USD 59,99; maybe it would be worth the expense. **The fact that you can image the disk means that in all likelihood the hardware is flawless. We're looking at a software malfunction here** (unless you had the bloody bad luck of a sector hardware malfunction in a critical area).

Comment: @Isreni -Thank u :)  

Today I used a seagate recovery software (free version) and it is able to read the HDD, list all the folder (as they were) and can recover all files less than 64kb (its free version). That means HDD is surely free from any hardware error.

After copying 200GB data to my laptop using dd, can I access that dump like we access normal directories? No..right..Because the dump created is a file which cannot be opened with any normal application installed. Then how can we extract/copy the required folder/file from that dump?

Comment: You need to do that on Linux (or have a tool that can access a file/image instead of a device; in Unix/Linux, they are the same thing, not so in Windows). You can mount the partial image as a loop device. Alternately, since the disk HW is working, you can do it the other way round and repair the *physical* disk. Then if things go awry, you can use `dd` to *restore the image of the originally damaged data on the physical disk*; but you will only be able to restore the data you imaged (the first 200 GB or so).

Comment: @Isreni - I tried as per your suggestion. Since the procedure i followed can not be explained in the word limit of the comment, I posted it here with command output. Please do have a look.  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6595122/

Comment: Running "fdisk image.img" gives the below output. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6595200/

Comment: Sorry, you need to image /dev/sdb, not /dev/sdb1 -- otherwise you're trusting the current partition table, which is unreliable. That's why fdisk croaks.

Comment: tried this time with /dev/sdc instead of /dev/sdc1 (this time HDD was recognized as sdc instead of sdb), but still the same error is coming while mounting the loop0 to dirctory.

I tried to mount the HDD directly to a directory and the below message was displayed. please have a look. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6598456/


If i dont need the data anymore , Can I format the HDD using 'format' command in windows. Will this fix the problem and make HDD accessible.?

Comment: Adding to answer...

Comment: "fdisk /dev/dsc" output is here -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/6598631/ 

"dd" output is here with different count numbers (see the output with count=100, first line have NTFS signature) -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/6598651/ 

see this ->  http://paste.ubuntu.com/6598669/

Answer (score -2):

just go to cmd as an Administrative privilege and type chkdsk X: /f
("X" is Driver's volume name, "/f" is fix)

Comment: @Iserni answer left the answer level too high, sorry but i must downvote

Comment: From OP: "Even chkdsk is failing now with the error: "The file system is NTFS. Unable to determine volume version and state. chkdsk aborted.""

Answer (score -3):

A simplir solution that for me and for my colleagues was to mount the disk and use `chkdsk` on Windows 7.